# update column values as each row data

Tags: php, date

I have table like this

| year | month | day | gregorian |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1400 | 01 | 01 | NULL |
| 1400 | 02 | 04 | NULL |
| 1390 | 11 | 11 | NULL |
| .... | ..... | ... | NULL |

and i want something like

| year | month | day | gregorian |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1400 | 01 | 01 | 2021-03-21 |
| 1400 | 02 | 04 | 2021-04-25 |
| .... | ..... | ... | ......... |

what i think sholud i do is

step 1 : i get date values (year,month,day) of each row 
step 2 : conver it from jalali date to gregorian "**i allready have `jalali_to_gregorian()` function in php**" 
step 3 : and put generated value to gregorian table

*there is no way in mysql to convert jalali to gregorian directly so i sholud use php*

so i use code like

```
$query = "select * from `table`";
$result = mysqli_query($database,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result){
 $gregorian = jalali_to_gregorian($row['year'],$row['month'],$row['day']);
 $innerQuery = "update `table` set `gregorian` = $gregorian"
 mysqli_query($database,$innerQuery)
}
```

so it's not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update is not restricted to an id or a where clause. Best way is always having row IDs or indexes.

But for you case following update query should work.

```
$innerQuery = "update `table` set `gregorian` = $gregorian WHERE `year`={$row['year']} AND `month`={$row['month']} AND `day`={$row['day']}";
```